# How to take sum of time value using sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **ReportBuilder** class for generate document (Excel). what i want is selecting **employee** and **date period** then calculate total **working hour**s for that date period. this is my php file

```
<?php
class EmployeeSummaryTimesheet extends ReportBuilder{

    public function getMainQuery(){
        $query = "SELECT
(SELECT `employee_id` from Employees where id = at.employee) as 'Employee',
(SELECT concat(`first_name`,' ',`middle_name`,' ', `last_name`) from Employees where id = at.employee) as 'Employee',

TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time) as 'Working Hours'
FROM Attendance at";

        return $query;
}

public function getWhereQuery($request){
        if(($request['employee'] != "NULL" && !empty($request['employee']))){
            $query = "where employee = ? and in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? group by employee;";
            $params = array(
                $request['employee'],
                $request['date_start']." 00:00:00",
                $request['date_end']." 23:59:59",
            );
        }else{
            $query = "where in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? group by employee;";
            $params = array(
                $request['date_start']." 00:00:00",
                $request['date_end']." 23:59:59",
            );
        }
 return array($query, $params);
    }}
```

now i cant get sum of that particular date period im getting first day **TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time)** value only not sum of working hours help me

EDit - Here i have two table Employee and Attendance (id,employee(this is employee id from Employee table),in_time,out_time)

Edit : i take off DATE_FORMAT(in_time, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date', i dont need this column

Comment: Are `out_time` and `in_time` from `Emplyees` table?

Comment: in the `getMainQuery` function you have two references to `Employee` as the result of individual select statements...

Comment: @Phate01 employee, in_time,out_time column in attendance table

Comment: @RamRaider yes if dont select employee select all employee get them working hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer i did my self

```
    public function getMainQuery(){

        $query = "SELECT
(SELECT `employee_id` from Employees where id = at.employee) as 'Employee',
(SELECT concat(`first_name`,' ',`middle_name`,' ', `last_name`) from Employees where id = at.employee) as 'Employee',
DATE_FORMAT(in_time, '%Y-%m') as 'MONTH',
CONCAT(
FLOOR(
SUM(CASE WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))<=0 THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))=''
ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time)) END)/3600) ,':',
FLOOR(MOD(
SUM(CASE WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))<=0 THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))=''
ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time)) END),3600)/60)) as 'WORKING HOURS'
FROM Attendance at";

        return $query;

    }

    public function getWhereQuery($request){
        if(($request['employee'] != "NULL" && !empty($request['employee']))){
            $query = "where employee = ? and in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? order by in_time;";
            $params = array(
                $request['employee'],
                $request['date_start']." 00:00:00",
                $request['date_end']." 23:59:59",
            );
        }else{
            $query = "where in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? group by employee;";
            $params = array(
                $request['date_start']." 00:00:00",
                $request['date_end']." 23:59:59",
            );
        }

        return array($query, $params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want one record per employee and date and display the employee's total working hours for that day. So join and group by employee and date and sum the working hours.

```
select
  e.employee_id,
  concat(e.first_name, ' ', e.middle_name, ' ', e.last_name) as employee_name 
  date_format(at.in_time, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date',
  sum(timediff(at.out_time, at.in_time)) as 'Working Hours'
from attendance at
join employee e on e.id = at.employee
where ...
group by e.employee_id, date_format(at.in_time, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: Hi ,this is our HR System already developd now im doing some development so i think to generate document we need to use getQuery and MainQuery i dont know how to use ur idea in my code ....?

Comment: employee_id is my Employee table employee is FK in Attendance table

Comment: if i dont use group by employee here ` $query = "where employee = ? and in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? group by employee;";` then i will get data as row by row **name,date, working hours** perfect but i want get sum of working hours

Comment: As to your first question: Well, the query consist of a "main query" plus where clause plus group by clause. So simply edit your main query to match mine and add a function to add the group by clause. As to your comment regarding the employee_id: I don't understand. Your query gets the employee_id from employee where employee.id = attendance.employee. So does mine. As to your comment regarding group by: No, your query doesn't group yet, but it has to, so add it.

Comment: yes employee_id comment correct urs and if i don't use  `$query = "where employee = ? and in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? group by employee;";`  **group by**  here i will get under  **Employee , Date , Woking Hours**  row by row same employee name each dates if i select date between 1 to 5 i will get deatils every name 1/11 wWH, name ,2/11,WH.........name,5/11,WH so its grouping thir ryt i dont knw im correct

Comment: you r telling to use where query into Main query .....? but Report builder class `public function getData($report,$request){
  $query = $this->getMainQuery();
  $where = $this->getWhereQuery($request);
  $query.=" ".$where[0];
  return $this->execute($report, $query, $where[1]);
 }`

Comment: You select the employee and a date and the working hours. So I guessed you want one result row per employee and date. If you only want one row per customer, then what is that 'Date' supposed to be? E.g. if you select dates 1/11 to 5/11, which of these do you want to show?

Comment: yes if i take off grop by `$query = "where employee = ? and in_time >= ? and out_time <= ? group by employee;";` here i will get data name date working hours **row by row** but i want by employee one row name and (ohwwww sorry this is month report  so i will selct date start of month and then end of month ) date colum shd b month name and third column shd b woking hours :(

Comment: sorry answer me im trubling two days :(

Comment: If you want this per month, then change `date_format(at.in_time, '%Y-%m-%d')` to `date_format(at.in_time, '%Y-%m')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96335/discussion-between-prudential-developer-and-thorsten-kettner).